# How can i modify elements of a List in a for loop

Tags: android, list, loops, for-loop, kotlin

I want to compare version names but to do so I have to conform them to the same standard, i.e. Major.Minor.Patch (1.3.21 for example).
Problem is I can't change the element i'm iterating over.

I store the versions as List and then all versions in another list that I pass as a variable to the following function.

```
var version_a = listOf(1)
var version_b = listOf(1, 2)
var version_c = listOf(1, 2, 3)
val versions = listOf(version_a, version_b, version_c)
adjustLengthExample(versions)

fun adjustLengthExample(versions: List<List<Int>>){
   for((index, version) in versions.withIndex()){
      while(version.size < 3){  
         version = mutableListOf().addAll(version).add(0) //using element: Error Val cannot be reassigned

         versions[index] = mutableListOf().addAll(version).add(0) //using indexed position: Error: No set method providing array access
      }
   }
}
versions.foreach(Log.d(TAG, it.toString())) //Expected output: [1,0,0][1,2,0][1,2,3]
```

How can I access version_a/b/c and set/change it's value?

Comment: you should use `val versions = mutableListOf(version_a, version_b, version_c)`

Comment: This actually seams to be working :)
Im such a schmuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
var version_a = listOf(1)
```

use

```
val version_a = mutableListOf(1)
```

then in the `while`loop just change the list`s content

```
while(version.size < 3) {  
    version.add(0) 
    // or
    versions[index].add(0) 
}
```

Here is the full example:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {

    fun adjustLengthExample(versions: List<MutableList<Int>>){
        for((index, version) in versions.withIndex()){
            while(version.size < 3){
                version.add(0)
                // or
                //versions[index].add(0)
            }
        }
    }

    val version_a = mutableListOf(1)
    val version_b = mutableListOf(1, 2)
    val version_c = mutableListOf(1, 2, 3)
    val versions = listOf(version_a, version_b, version_c)

    adjustLengthExample(versions)

    versions.forEach { println(it) } 
}
```

This outputs:

```
[1, 0, 0]
[1, 2, 0]
[1, 2, 3]
```

To do the same with immutable lists new lists have to be created and `adjustLengthExample` has to return the new list. Like this:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {

    fun adjustLengthExample(versions: List<List<Int>>): List<List<Int>> {
        var result: List<List<Int>> = listOf()

        for ((index, version) in versions.withIndex()) {
            var newVersion: List<Int> = version
            while (newVersion.size < 3) {
                newVersion += 0
            }
            result += listOf(newVersion)
        }
        return result
    }

    val version_a = listOf(1)
    val version_b = listOf(1, 2)
    val version_c = listOf(1, 2, 3)
    var versions = listOf(version_a, version_b, version_c)

    versions = adjustLengthExample(versions)

    versions.forEach { println(it) } 
}
```

Comment: This probably works, but I don't want to make the lists mutable since they are part of a data model and thus will be passed around.
My hope was that making them variables (var) i could override them with a new value. 
Is my logic flawed?

Comment: As you used `... version = mutableListOf() ...` I thought mutable lists are ok. Nevertheless as you want to change the lists I would consider mutable lists the better choice.

Comment: Added an example which works with immutable lists to my answer

Comment: Thanks for taking your time.
I went with the last example and it works as intended.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

There's a much easier way to achieve that:

```
val versions = listOf(listOf(1), listOf(1, 2), listOf(1, 2, 3))

val result = versions.map {
    (it + listOf(0, 0, 0)).subList(0, 3)
}

println(result)
```

Output:

```
[[1, 0, 0], [1, 2, 0], [1, 2, 3]]
```